# Jquery Colorbox issue with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I am populating anchor links in repeater through javascript, I am poping up the those links with colorbox iframe.
Its working fine in IE7,Safari, Chrome, but not in Forefox(14.1).

In firefox its opening in a new window, instead of opening in colorbox iframe.

```
function BidCountFormatter(BidCount, AuctionID) {
if (parseInt(BidCount) > 0)
    return "<b><a class=auctionhistorybox href=popupauctionhistory.aspx?auctionid=" + AuctionID + ">" + BidCount + "</a></b>";
else
    return "--";
}

$(document).ready(function () {
          $(".auctionhistorybox").colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "35%", height: "60%" });
      });
```

Comment: ... are you sure this is not related to security settings inf FF, as in iframes being disallowed?

Comment: yes, I am sure, because putting simply anchor tag like <a class="auctionhistorybox" href="popupauctionhistory.aspx?auctionid=5">Click Me</a> is working in FF.

Comment: ... any errors? what about adding single quotes to param values?

Comment: no luck, i tried adding single or double quotes as well.

Comment: ... no errors in the console though?

Comment: no errors in the Error console

Comment: ... hm, nothing sticks out or I'm overlooking something. can you do a http://jsfiddle.net/ mockup?

Comment: ... come to think of it, what version of jquery are you using? Since those links are dynamically generated, did you try biding the click event to them through http://api.jquery.com/on/ (or 'live' for older jquery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the anchor links were dynamically generated at run time, so I had to rebind ColorBox events after that:

instead of doing " $(document).ready"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".auctionhistorybox").colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "35%", height: "60%" });
});
```

I called below function after generating the "auctionhistorybox" links in repeater

```
function bindColorBoxEvents() {
$('.auctionhistorybox').each(function (i) {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $(".auctionhistorybox").colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "50%", height: "95%" });
});
```

}

appreciate your help @Vector.